# Error 3027, Database or object is ready only?

Tags: vba, ms-access

When I run the code blow on, it stops and gives me an error

```
 3027
Database or Object is Read only
```

When I clicked debug, it pointed at rec.edit.

Yet I have no idea how it is read only. I did check to make sure that the object was closed and the same error still came up.   The person who came up with it said it worked for them and that they didn't have any issues with readonly. Any ideas?

```
 Public Function HitTest()

    Dim db As Database
    Dim rec As DAO.Recordset
    Dim fld As DAO.Field

    Set db = CurrentDb
    Set rec = db.OpenRecordset("PlayerSal")
    EditTable = "PlayerSal"

    For Each fld In rec.Fields
      If fld.Name <> "Name" And fld.Name <> "Salary" And Left(fld.Name, 4) <> "Per_" Then
        strFieldName = "Per_" & fld.Name & ""
        'rs.Fields (strFieldName)
        'X = "IIf(rec([" & fld.Name & "]) <> 0, Format((rec([Salary]) / rec([" & fld.Name & "])), '$#,###.##'), 0)"
        If FieldExists(EditTable, strFieldName) Then
        Else
            'AltTable = "ALTER TABLE " & EditTable & " ADD COLUMN " & strFieldName & " Double;"
            'CurrentDb.Execute (AltTable)
        End If
            rec.Edit
            X = IIf(rec((fld.Name)) <> 0, Format((rec("Salary") / rec((fld.Name))), "$#,###.##"), 0)
            rec.Fields(strFieldName).Value = X
            rec.Update
      End If
    Next fld

    End Function
```

Because I know that Access can be really silly at times, I decided to try a new Database and just import the few files I needed. I've had times where doing that randomly makes things work for some reason. When I imported the module you see below, it then stopped at the

```
 If FeildsExists(EditTable, strFieldName)
```

and it said Sub or Function not defined... I don't know if either of these two are related to something simple.. but this is getting silly... especially when the guy who put this together had it work fine.

Comment: change to this: `Set rec = db.OpenRecordset("PlayerSal", dbOpenDynaset)` I think you need that dynaset in there.

Comment: You might want to make that an answer.

Comment: That didn't fix anything for me. I will also add though, I tried it on a different Database, and it gave me a different error.. although unrelated to your input. I had this error when I tried it yesterday.

Comment: Is PlayerSal a local Access table? If so, I assume you can open it and see the contents in a Data Sheet. Can you change the contents in the Data Sheet?

Answer (score 1):

I know the second half.  :o)  Your function name is wrong.  You have "If FeildsExists" and it should be "If FieldExists".