# How to get .edit to work in MS Access when using workaround to auto-send emails via Outlook on Office 365 ProPlus?

Tags: vba, ms-access, outlook, office365

When using the .Send function I encountered run-time error '287' due to Outlook security, hence did a workaround by using .Display with SendKeys "%{s}",True, which works. Issue is that I only want to auto-send the emails once and when using this workaround, the .Edit portion that follows throws up run-time error '438' upon sending the first email in the batch. How do I get this portion of the code to work?

Am using various codes found online with some tweaks and not sure where to adjust currently.

```
Function GenerateEmail(MySQL As String)
Dim oOutlook As Outlook.Application
Dim oEmailItem As MailItem

Dim rs As Recordset
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(MySQL)
If rs.RecordCount > 0 Then
    rs.MoveFirst
    Do Until rs.EOF
    If IsNull(rs!A_Email) Then
            rs.MoveNext
    Else
        If oOutlook Is Nothing Then
        Set oOutlook = New Outlook.Application
        End If

        Set oEmailItem = oOutlook.CreateItem(0)
        With oEmailItem
            .To = rs!A_Email
            .CC = rs!B_Email
            .Subject = "Text "
            .Body = "Text " & vbCr & _
                   "Text " & vbCr & _
                   "Text!"
            .Display
            SendKeys "%{s}", True
            '.Send
            .Edit
            rs!First_Auto_Reminder_Sent = Date
            rs.Update

    End With
    Set oEmailItem = Nothing
    Set oOutlook = Nothing
    rs.MoveNext
    End If
    Loop
Else
    ' do nothing
End If
rs.Close
Exit_Function:
    Exit Function
End Function
```

Expected results: Access auto sends emails and updates the First_Auto_Reminder_Sent column with current date, so that email reminder is only sent once (as there is a criteria to set First_Auto_Reminder_Sent to "Is Null" in query). Runtime error '438' is encountered currently.

Comment: What is the exact error message? Why use .Edit? I never have.

Comment: Exact error message: "Run-time error '438': Object doesn't support this property or method." Used .Edit only because an example on YouTube used it and the script worked (together with .Send function). Perhaps I should use something else instead?

Comment: Did you try without Edit? I am not even seeing it is a method of Outlook mail item. It does not show in intellisense popup tip and see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Outlook.MailItem

Comment: I tried greying out the .Edit by putting a ' in front, an error then occurred in the next line, after sending out the first email - "Runtime error '3265': Item not found in this collection."

Answer (score 1):

`Edit` method is for the recordset so you need to qualify with `rs` prefix

```
            rs.Edit
            rs!First_Auto_Reminder_Sent = Date
            rs.Update
```

Comment: You have earned the `Eagle eye` badge.

Comment: Thanks, but it took me way too long to recognize the Edit went with the recordset and not the mail item. That itself is embarrassing.

Comment: Thanks both, entered rs and on running, first email is sent out followed by error: "Run-time error '3027': Cannot update. Database or object is read-only." Database is currently sitting on my desktop, is there a setting I need to adjust manually or via VBA script? Based on link below, I adjusted portion "Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(MySQL, dbOpenDynaset)", but same error with rs.Edit highlighted appears: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16969367/error-3027-database-or-object-is-ready-only

Comment: I tested your code. I don't get that error. Emails are sent and records updated.

Comment: But I am not using Office365, just Access 2010 on laptop.

Comment: Ok, will redo and see if it works - not sure where the issue is currently.